# Two adjacent divs don't touch in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to make a tabbed interface in a webpage, with a slight transparency. I am quite close to what I want, but there is a problem with it - and it is browser dependent.

For UX reasons, I want the "page" below the tab to look really connected to the tab, so the tab doesn't float above it. The problem is, when they are flush in Chrome, there is an overlap in Firefox, and when they are flush in Firefox, there is a gap in Chrome. And because of the transparency, the overlap changes the color and looks bad.

Making markup changes is very hard to impossible on this page. It needs a CSS solution.

This is what I want it to look like.

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uwULR/

The code is

```
<div class="tabs" id="searchSwitchers">
        <input type="button" id="StandardSearchButton" value="Standard search" class="SearchFormButton switchableTab-inactive" autocomplete="off"/>
        <input type="button" id="AdvancedSearchButton" value="Advanced search" class="SearchFormButton switchableTab-active"autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="tabbed">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

The style:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
}


.tabbed {
      -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
          padding-left: 1em;
          padding-right: 1em;
          padding-bottom: 1em;
          margin-left: -1em;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-top: -2px; /*This makes it work in Chrome but breaks it in Firefox*/
}

.switchableTab-active {
    color: #0047B9;
display: inline-block;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
padding: 0.5em 1.25em;
border-top-left-radius: 2em;
border-top-right-radius: 2em;

    border: none;
font-size: 1em;
}

.switchableTab-inactive {
    color: #5987d1;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0.5em 1.25em;
background-color: #CADDFA;
border-top-left-radius: 2em;
border-top-right-radius: 2em;
    border: none;
font-size: 1em;
}

div.tabs {
}

.switchableTab-inactive:hover {
border-right: 1px solid #5987d1;
border-top:1px solid #5987d1;
border-left:1px solid #5987d1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your s have border defined at 1px and inherited margins.

Adding

```
.tabs input[type='button'] {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-width:0px !important;
}
```

should do the trick

http://jsfiddle.net/PH75U/

Answer (score 1):

Normally when used `display:inline-block` for 2 div align next to each other. This problem appear.

There are few methods to solve this issue; however I am giving another solution. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/uwULR/3/)**.

```
input.SearchFormButton{font-size:14px;} /*again set the font-size as parent element have size 0*/
div.tabs {
    font-size:0; /*giving font-size:0 space removed*/
}
```

Comment: The solution works, as long as I use a font size in pixel. For some reason it doesn't work when I set it in em. So thanks, and you get an upvote, but I will accept the other answer which also works with a responsive design.

Comment: @RumiP. thanks for sharing the knowledge with me.. it will help me also in future

Answer (score 0):

because you use inputs, which have inherited margins and borders...
use

```
input[type='button'] {
margin: 0;
border:none;
}
```

strong advice: do not use inputs for tabs... use divs and js

Comment: Sorry, but as I said above, I can't change the markup. There is a reason why these are inputs.

Comment: and a gave you a working CSS snippet for button inputs

Comment: "do not use inputs for tabs" was just an advice